# Maths in php giving wrong answer

Tags: php, variables, math, equation

I have a simple equation written in PHP. I have tried to replicate the equation bellow.

When I work out the Equation on pager using the variables I have provided in the PHP I get 2,467.86 (using equation A).

But when I run it in PHP I get 4,2267.11, where have I gone wrong in my PHP ?

**Equation A**
[image]

**PHP Equation**

```
<?php
$p = 0;
$i = 0.06;
$c = 12;
$n = 1;
$r = 200;

$x = $i / $c;
$y = pow((1 + $x), ($n * $c));

$vf = $p * $y + (($r * $y - 1) / $x);
?>
<p>Answer:<?php echo $vf; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
$vf = $p * $y + ($r * ($y - 1) / $x);
// outputs 2467.1124745799
```

Your equation was:

```
$vf = $p * $y + (($r * $y - 1) / $x); // <- NOT $r*$y -1 , but $r*($y-1)
```

You can see it [here - 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/fr8ib)